# Split rows into columns MySQL

Tags: mysql

I just have no idea what the correct syntax for create view.

table **employee**

```
|nik    |   name  |

 112         john

 113         smith
```

---

table **absen**

```
|kode_asben| ket_absen|

   hdr       Hadir

   skt         sakit
```

---

table **detail_absen**

```
|NIK |Kode_absen|

112       hdr

113       skt

112       hdr

113       hdr
```

---

and here the view table should be

```
|nik   | Hadir   | Sakit |

112       2           0

113       1           1
```

---

Comment: will you please add your need...

Comment: solved already thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT nik,
       SUM(Kode_absen = 'hdr') Hadir,
       SUM(Kode_absen = 'skt') Sakit
  FROM detail_absen 
 GROUP BY nik
```

or

```
SELECT e.nik,
       IFNULL(SUM(d.kode_absen = 'hdr'), 0) Hadir,
       IFNULL(SUM(d.kode_absen = 'skt'), 0) Sakit
  FROM employee e LEFT JOIN detail_absen d 
    ON e.nik = d.nik
 GROUP BY e.nik;
```

depending on your needs

Sample output:

```
| NIK | HADIR | SAKIT |
|-----|-------|-------|
| 112 |     2 |     0 |
| 113 |     1 |     1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a83d3e/2)** demo

Comment: wow it's really short syntax than syntax what i was created thanks